# How to enable horizontal scrolling of text in NStextView window for OSX application?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, scrollview

I have spent quite a time with Xcode without a solution, I miss in Xcode a simple feature for OSX application. When I past or type text in the NStextView window, this text should be continued on the right and I can scroll horizontally. Instead now, the text go on the next line and I have only vertical scrolling. What I have to do in xcode setting to have horizontal scrolling without jumping on the line below?

Comment: You have to set NSTextView's maximum width to a very large number and then enable horizontal scrolling of its NSScrollView.

Comment: @rocky I am sorry, but I still cannot find in assistance editor what to change. I have – Borderd Scroll View,  Clip View and Text View. Could you write exactly where from these three and what I have to change in the settings?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only have the Objective-C:

```
[self.scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:YES]; 
[self.textView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[self.textView setHorizontallyResizable:YES];
[[self.textView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
[[self.textView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
        textView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
        textView.isHorizontallyResizable = true
        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
        textView.textContainer?.containerSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
```